# jQuery change image back and forth

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
 <img id="voteImgBtn" onclick='editInstr(1);' src="http://site.com/sync.png" width="99" height="99" border="0"  />
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function changeImage(a) {
                            document.getElementById("voteImgBtn").src=a;
                        }
                    </script>
```

Then i change the image on click and after my ajax's success as follows

```
 success: function(data){
           changeImage( "http://site.com/syncD.png" );
        }
```

What I want to do is have a delay after the changeImage and put back the old image like so:

```
 success: function(data){
           changeImage( "http://site.com/syncD.png" );
           delay(500).changeImage( "http://site.com/sync.png" );
        }
```

But for some reason that does not work. Could you give a suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: See `setTimeout` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: I found a way to do this using the `delay` function (outlined below). It was strictly an academic exercise though. Not sure if it would ever offer an advantage over `setTimeout` for code that doesn't involve a jQuery animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is neither chainable nor a jQuery animation, which is the only thing `delay()` works on (anything in the .fx queue to be more precise), try something like this :

```
success: function(data){
    changeImage( "http://site.com/syncD.png" );
    setTimeout(function() {
        changeImage( "http://site.com/sync.png" );
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, yes it works. javaScript is a complete mystery to me. Will have to read more about what works when. Thanks again. Will accept your answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`delay` is a jQuery function not a standard JavaScript function.

```
$().delay()
```

**Edit:**

After searching around, I found [an obscure way](http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1559) to achieve this using the `delay` function (shown below). But you're probably far better off using `setTimeout` as suggested by others.

```
// Queue it in the fx queue
$(document).delay(500).queue(function(){ 
    changeImage( "http://site.com/sync.png" );
    $(this).dequeue(); 
});

// Queue it in a custom queue
$(document).delay(500, 'myQueue').queue('myQueue', function(){
    alert('hello');
}).dequeue('myQueue');
```

Comment: Very interesting answer. Glad you shared it with us. Have a great weekend.