# Change webpage back and forth using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, delay

It is an ASP.NET MVC web application for which I wish to display content of two different websites after a delay of 30 seconds. The two websites are properly displayed given their respective URLs. Now, ***only remains to swap the two pages after the given delay***.

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller { 
    public HomeController(SomeViewModel viewModel, Uri otherWebsiteUri) {
        this.otherWebsiteUrl = otherWebsiteUrl;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult OtherWebsite() {
        return View(otherWebsiteUrl);
    }

    private Uri otherWebsiteUri;
    private SomeViewModel viewModel;
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.SomeViewModel

@section header {
    <!-- Header content here... -->
}

<div>
    <!-- Page content here... -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var displayWebsiteContent = function ( url ) { 
            $.get(url, $( body ).html(data)); 
        };

        var milliseconds = 30000;
        var rootUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;
        var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
        var otherWebsiteUrl = rootUrl + "/Home/OtherWebsite";

        $( "body" ).delay( milliseconds ).queue( function() {
            if ( currentUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf( "other" ))
                displayWebsiteContent(rootUrl);
            else
                displayWebsiteContent(otherWebsiteUrl);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**OtherWebsite.cshtml**

```
@model System.Uri

<iframe src="@Html.DisplayForm(m => m.AbsoluteUri)" 
        width="98%" 
        height="1000px" 
        frameborder="0" 
        scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

So far, I have come across these related SO Q/A:

- [**jQuery change image back and forth**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048895/jquery-change-image-back-and-forth)
- [**Delay AJAX call for X seconds**](http://www.sitepoint.com/delay-ajax-call-seconds/)
- [**jQuery Ajax failing to call to MVC 4 Controller method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173635/jquery-ajax-failing-to-call-to-mvc-4-controller-method)
- [**MVC ajax calling controller method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700335/mvc-ajax-calling-controller-method)
- [**jquery delay between javascript functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782057/jquery-delay-between-javascript-functions)
- [**create a delay between the running of functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105307/create-a-delay-between-the-running-of-functions)
- [**jQuery delay between animations**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951528/jquery-delay-between-animations)

I thought that I had to put the jQuery delay script inside the **Index.cshtml** as this is the first page being loaded, and that I do not which the timer to execute when outside of these two pages/controller methods.

Any hints and tips on how to make it?

> **EDIT** *Following [Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27429067/162167)'s recommendation*

I have opted for a single script per page which redirects to each page.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var displayWebsiteContent = function ( url ) { 
            $.get(url, $( body ).html( data )); 
        };

        var milliseconds = 30000;
        var rootUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;
        var otherWebsiteUrl = rootUrl + "/Home/OtherWebsite";

        $( "body" ).delay( milliseconds ).queue( function() { 
            displayWebsiteContent( otherWebsiteUrl ); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

**OtherWebsite.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var displayWebsiteContent = function ( url ) { 
            $.get(url, $( body ).html( data )); 
        };

        var milliseconds = 30000;
        var rootUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;            

        $( "body" ).delay( milliseconds ).queue( function() { 
            displayWebsiteContent( rootUrl ); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Notice that I have blindly tried to add the `<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js">` and the behaviour changed from `Microsoft runtime error: '$' is undefined` to an almost working piece of code.

Only now, an exception or the like is thrown stating that `data` is not declared, which I can partially understand. So I have also tried the following while doing the get request.

```
var displayWebsiteContent = function ( url ) {
    $.get( url
        , function ( data ) {
              $( body ).html( data );
          });
};
```

And this does nothing.

To make it clear, I wish to be able to perform this:

```
Index() (wait 30 seconds)
OtherWebsite() (wait 30 seconds)
Index() (wait 30 seconds)
OtherWebsite() (wait 30 seconds)
...
```

> **EDIT** *After further diggings, following Chris Pratt's hints about having a script on each single page the swapping is applicable to.*

**Solution**

Further diggings conducted me to find this solution which was the missing masterpiece to my chef-d'oeuvre. =P

[**MVC Redirect to View from jQuery with parameters**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510023/mvc-redirect-to-view-from-jquery-with-parameters)

The key to the masterpiece is `window.location.href` over the `$.get()` method.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var displayWebsiteContent = function ( url ) { 
            window.location.href = url; 
        };

        var milliseconds = 30000;
        var rootUrl = window.location.protocol 
                    + "//" 
                    + window.location.host;

        $( "body" ).delay( milliseconds ).queue( function() { 
            displayWebsiteContent( rootUrl ); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

**OtherWebsite**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var displayWebsiteContent = function ( url ) { 
            window.location.href = url;
        };

        var milliseconds = 30000;
        var rootUrl = window.location.protocol 
                    + "//" 
                    + window.location.hostname;            

        $( "body" ).delay( milliseconds ).queue( function() { 
            displayWebsiteContent( rootUrl ); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Et voilà !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript on page is only good for that page. You can't write JavaScript that applies to the actual browser tab/window or something outside of creating a browser extension. So, you can either add code to each page that redirects you to the other, or pretty much your only other option is to use a frameset or iframe, such that you can have some global JavaScript that cycles the frame/iframe URL without having to actually move off the main loaded page in the browser tab/window.

Comment: I'd be glad to simply add the code necessary to redirect to each page. I have tried something and I can't get it to work. I'll edit in a few.